# Restful web service API user authentication on every single call

Tags: php, android

I need to create a REST api to authenticate a user the first time and retrieve other information based on this user for subsequent calls. If I'm not mistaken Restful services are stateless and therefore there is no need to store user information server side. My question is how can I guarantee user authentication for all the subsequent calls without a session?

This service is needed to create an android app that can display information on mobile.

Comment: Might be good to read up on OAuth2 - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: I do same thing in our app. First user is authenticated and session-value is returned from server. Then this session-value is stored in app and send in every call so user is identified. It works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) which is a widely used standard.

Another option is to use BASIC authentication over SSL. Any decent HTTP library would support BASIC auth. The client will be challenged the first time the request is made. Subsequent request need to send the BASIC auth headers over a secure line.

The there is the approach where you pass a secret to your client and use HMAC-SHA256 to send a hash of the URL params over to the server. Amazon does that and there is [an article that covers](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) how this is done. It is not as complicated as OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches available but IMO your best best is to generate a AuthToken server side and return that to the client upon successful login. Then the client includes this on every request down to the server.

What I typical do is create a MD5 hash of a secret key and the the user's id- user's username - user's password - and the current date time. Then I store the token and the current date time in the db. on look ups after that I decode the token and compare the data points against the db values and if they match the user is good. This way is stateless and easily scalable.